# My scrollview in a linear layout is pushing up other widgets above it

Tags: java, android, xml, android-scrollview

So my button and edit text widgets keep getting pushed upwards when I dynamically add text views to my scroll view. So the scrollview's height is also being bumped up. How do I just make sure the scroll view is fixed, I've looked at similar questions and tried implementing it but not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:hint="Enter name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone_num"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:hint="Enter Phone Number"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/submit_contact"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set all heights to 0dp and give the wheightSum to the parent view. To have a fixed height of the button surround it with a LinearLayout.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2.75"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:hint="Enter name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone_num"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:hint="Enter Phone Number"/>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="test"/>
        
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Try it out, If it dont work you may post what you have tried alredy and the code how you ad the textViews dynamicly. Good luck